# PIC18F97J60 interfacing with LT1661 chip

Tags: c, microchip

Currently I am trying to create a program that will output an analog signal to an LED using the LTC1661 chip with the PIC18F97J60.

The dac ltc1661 chip is connected to my board with the ports:
RC3 for SCK1
RC5 for SDO1
with the data pin being connected to my 8bit SPIBUF buffer.

Here is my code, its outputting to the led but I can't seem to make the led gradually increase in bright ness, its just a sudden on and off.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include "amt.h"
#include <p18f97j60.h>

int main(void) {
    TRISCbits.RC3 = 0;
    TRISCbits.RC5 = 0;
    TRISCbits.RC7 = 0;

    SSP1CON1 = 0b00100010;  // Enable SPI, CKP=0, Master, Fosc/64
    SSP1STATbits.CKE = 1;   // CKE=1, (rising edge for shift register)

    char temp;

    while(1) {
        //SSP1BUF = 0x00;
        PORTCbits.RC7 = 0;
        SSP1BUF = 0x98;
        while(PIR1bits.SSPIF==0);
        SSP1BUF = 0x00;
        while(PIR1bits.SSPIF==0);
        PORTCbits.RC7 = 1;

        PORTCbits.RC7 = 0;
        SSP1BUF = 0x98;
        while(PIR1bits.SSPIF==0);
        SSP1BUF = 0x04;
        while(PIR1bits.SSPIF==0);
        PORTCbits.RC7 = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably you just need a sleep between iterations of your outer while loop?

Comment: Using `char` for storing raw data is a bug. Use `uint8_t`. Overall, the use of `stdint.h` is mandatory in embedded systems. Also PIC is a slow 8 bitter, not a PC. Thus avoid 16 bit types or bigger when they aren't needed.

Comment: ...and now you radically changed the code to a short snippet that sends a few magic numbers over SPI. What's the meaning of the magic numbers? And more importantly whats your clock phase and polarity settings? A very brief glance at the datasheet suggests that this part uses half a bit clock phase and rising edge clocking. If this is true, then your SPI setup seems incomplete.